# CPradoViewRenderer does not process short tags

Tags: php, yii

I need help with CPradoViewRenderer. Since i changed my main.tpl i see on web page the output:

[image]

The short tags are not being processed by renderer class. The object of CPradoViewRenderer initialized and.

`echo get_class(Yii::app()->getViewRenderer())` return `CPradoViewRenderer`

I've not changed CPradoViewRenderer class and it worked fine to this moment

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with mbstring.func_overload(I had value 2) in php.ini. 
App works correct with mbstring.func_overload = 0